How to select a bone and pose the armature in weight paint mode
I'm a beginner and I tried to weight paint with a tutorial. I found that the teacher can select the bone and change the pose when weight painting using "Ctrl+LMB" so that she don't need to change mode frequently. I tried the same operation but nothing happend - I cannot change the bone I'm seleting and let alone changing pose.
So I searched the official document and community but nothing helped. I also asked an experienced pal and he told me to disable Face Mask. But that was no help. I even reset my blender settings and disabled all plug-ins but it still doesn't work!
There might be a problem is that I once copied (using Ctrl C+V) a mesh from a blend file, but that was an old version (I don't know which version) file and I didn't know if it used any plug-ins. The pal told me it might be the problem.
My blender version is 4.0, and the tutorial I'm following is a tutorial to make a VRchat avatar using blender 3.6 with plug-in blender cats.
One more thing. I installed blender 4.1.1 tried to avoid the problem but after I open it, I accidently chose "using the settings in blender 4.0" and now it has the same problem. OH MY GOD

Weight painting has changed in Blender 4. This is explained in this short video from Grant Abbitt

Oh thanks! I didn't even think about that the shortcut has been changed since the official document still say that is Ctrl + LMB but it has actually changed to Ctrl + Shift + LMB!

The problem has been solved thanks to John Eason in the comment of the question.
The shortcut key has changed to Ctrl + Shift + LMB in Blender 4.0. I have thought about this posibility but the official document did not update this.
I actually tried this shortcut, before I disabled Face Mask. So it didn't work. That is too unfortunate.

Hmm... Not sure how you report a bug in the documentation! :^)
